# Setup a SBT project for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, playframework, sbt

I've a backend implemented with Scala and Play and want to create a separate project for the frontend. Is there a tutorial or simple example that shows hot to setup a SBT project for AngularJS? I've googled a bit and most of the examples are for Play with AngularJS... but in my case, there is no Play stuff in the frontend project... it is a pure AngularJS application that uses a REST API implemented with Play.

Comment: How will your frontend app be served? Using Play HTTP server or another technology(ex Apache/nginx)? Unless you want to make Play serve that app also or use Play routing IMO there are no many advantages of using SBT...

Comment: Since the frontend is completely separated from the backend, to run it I need to setup tomcat or jetty manually, copy the AngularJS files to the webapp folder, etc. I want to be able to `sbt run` and have the application responding, like a Play app.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this make no sense. If the client application is a pure AngularJS application then it should be deployed like a pure AngualarJS application. This means you could use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/), [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) or any other lightweight HTTP server to serve your application.

If you want to stay with your idea, then you could use [Play Yeoman](https://github.com/tuplejump/play-yeoman) without the Play stuff.